# Equality between rank and dimension

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, localization, local-rings

Let $M$ a finitely generated module over a noetherian commutative ring $A$. Assume that $M_{\mathfrak p}$ is a free $A_{\mathfrak p}$-module. For any prime $\mathfrak p$ and let's  put $k(\mathfrak p):=A_{\mathfrak p}/\mathfrak pA_\mathfrak p$.

How can I prove the following equality:

> $$\operatorname{dim}_{k(\mathfrak p)}M\otimes_A k(\mathfrak p) =\operatorname{rank}_{A_{\mathfrak p}}(M_{\mathfrak p})$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $\Lambda$  is the rank. Then 
$$
\begin{aligned}
M\otimes_{A}k(\mathfrak{p})=&
(M\otimes_{A}A_\mathfrak{p})\otimes_{A_\mathfrak{p}}k(\mathfrak{p})=
M_\mathfrak{p}\otimes_{A_\mathfrak{p}}k(\mathfrak{p})\\
=&A_\mathfrak{p}^{\oplus \Lambda}\otimes_{A_\mathfrak{p}}k(\mathfrak{p})=
(A_\mathfrak{p}\otimes_{A_\mathfrak{p}}k(\mathfrak{p}))^{\oplus \Lambda}=k(\mathfrak{p})^{\oplus \Lambda}
\end{aligned}
$$